# Scrapy + Selenium - how to use search bar after log in

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, webdriver

I am currently new in Webscraping topic.
I've created Selenium scraper successfully.
Now, I want to do the same with Scrapy.
I've checked the site (using robots.txt) and it allows to **scrape** using robots.
I have log in code:

```
class QuotesSpider(Spider):
    name = 'scr'
    start_urls = ('https://alison.com/login',)
    def parse(self, response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                         formdata={'password': 'aaa',
                                                   'email': 'aaa'},
                                         callback=self.scrape_pages)
 
    def scrape_pages(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
```

Now, I need to find Finance related courses.
Here is the successful Selenium code:

```
    search=driver.find_element_by_id("autocomplete")
    search.send_keys("Finance")
    driver.find_element_by_id("search_icon").click()
    time.sleep(10)
```

What should I add and where into my Scrapy code to make it work?
I've heard that there is as well Scrapy+Selenium approach, but I have no idea how to implement this.
I couldn't find any up to date tutorial about this case.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: you can start directly with selenium, or check the network tab to see what the request is that search "Finance" then do it in scrapy

Comment: So do you suggest to import Selenium into my Scrapy file and then do everything as I did in Selenium? I've tried that but I did something wrong I guess. The method is GET. Could you give me more guideline? How to do it in Scrapy?

Answer (score 0):

```
class QuotesSpider(Spider):
    name = 'scr'
    start_urls = ('https://alison.com/login',)
    def parse(self, response):
        yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                         formdata={'password': 'aaa',
                                                   'email': 'aaa'},
                                         callback=self.scrape_pages)

    def scrape_pages(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
        #if you want to query
        #url = "https://alison.com/courses?query=finance"
        #if you want a specific course for example financial literacy
        url = "https://alison.com/course/financial-literacy"
        yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse_course)

    def parse_course(self,response):
        open_in_browser(response)
        #do your parsing here
```

Comment: I think there is error as in my cmd I get the information:  'spider_exceptions/NameError': 1, and only page after log in appears, not the next one with finance query.  I did the first way proposed by you, with url where query=finance. Maybe I should import something for scrapy.Request? `from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
import scrapy ` Am I missing something?

Comment: no you don't need to import anything else, query search for this website are sent as parameters, after you log in you just need to `get` the url you want